# Converting string to UTF8Type in FluentCassandra

Tags: f#, fluentcassandra

I am working with FluentCassandra in F# and attempting to convert a string to a UTF8Type in order to use the ExecuteNonQuery method.  Has anyone been successful doing this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Hi Tom! Would you mind posting the code you've tried so far, and also any details of the exact problem you ran into (e.g., exception messages or compiler errors)? Doing that makes it much more likely that someone will be able to help you solve the issue.

Comment: Looks [here](https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/src/Types/UTF8Type.cs) like there's an implicit conversion: `UTF8Type.op_Implicit str`. It might be handy to wrap that in a function/operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jack P. and Daniel for pointing me in the right direction.

To provide more examples so others can benefit, I am writing a wrapper on top of FluentCassandra in F# to make CRUD functionality much simpler by utilizing the succinctness of F#.  I am using Nick Berardi's code as an example for this wrapper:

https://github.com/fluentcassandra/fluentcassandra/blob/master/test/FluentCassandra.Sandbox/Program.cs

For example, if you want to check if a keyspace exists, simply calling the KeySpaceExists(keyspaceName) would allow for checking if a keyspace exists, using CreateKeyspace(keyspaceName) would allow for creation of a keyspace, etc.  An example of the library I am creating is here:

```
namespace Test

open System
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Configuration
open System.Linq
open System.Text
open System.Windows
open FluentCassandra
open FluentCassandra.Connections
open FluentCassandra.Types
open FluentCassandra.Linq

module Cassandra =
    let GetAppSettings (key : string) = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item(key)

    let KeyspaceExists keyspaceName =
        let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
        let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
        let keyspaceNameExists = db.KeyspaceExists(keyspaceName)
        db.Dispose()
        keyspaceNameExists

    let CreateKeyspace keyspaceName = 
        let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
        let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
        let schema = new CassandraKeyspaceSchema(Name=keyspaceName)
        let keyspace = new CassandraKeyspace(schema,db)
        if KeyspaceExists(keyspaceName)=false then keyspace.TryCreateSelf()
        db.Dispose()

    let DropKeyspace (keyspaceName : string ) =
        let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
        let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
        match db.KeyspaceExists(keyspaceName)=true with
            // value has "ignore" to ignore the string returned from FluentCassandra
            | true -> db.DropKeyspace(keyspaceName) |> ignore
            | _ -> ()
        db.Dispose()

    let ColumnFamilyExists (keyspaceName, columnFamilyName : string) = 
        let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
        let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
        let schema = new CassandraKeyspaceSchema(Name=keyspaceName)
        let keyspace = new CassandraKeyspace(schema,db)
        let columnFamilyNameExists = db.ColumnFamilyExists(columnFamilyName)
        db.Dispose()
        columnFamilyNameExists

    let CreateColumnFamily (keyspaceName, columnFamilyName: string) = 
        if ColumnFamilyExists(keyspaceName,columnFamilyName)=false then
            let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
            let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
            let schema = new CassandraKeyspaceSchema(Name=keyspaceName)
            let keyspace = new CassandraKeyspace(schema,db)

            if ColumnFamilyExists(keyspaceName,columnFamilyName)=false then
                keyspace.TryCreateColumnFamily(new CassandraColumnFamilySchema(FamilyName = columnFamilyName, KeyValueType = CassandraType.AsciiType, ColumnNameType = CassandraType.IntegerType, DefaultColumnValueType = CassandraType.UTF8Type))

    let ExecuteNonQuery(keyspaceName, query: string) = 
        let server = new Server(GetAppSettings("Server"))
        let db = new CassandraContext(keyspaceName, server)
        let schema = new CassandraKeyspaceSchema(Name=keyspaceName)
        let keyspace = new CassandraKeyspace(schema,db)
        let queryUTF8 = FluentCassandra.Types.UTF8Type.op_Implicit query
        try
            db.ExecuteNonQuery(queryUTF8)
            true
        with
            | _ -> false
```

This library allows for very easy one line commands to utilize the FluentCassandra functionality.  Of course this is just the start and I plan on amending the above library further.

```
open System
open System.Linq
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Configuration
open FluentCassandra.Connections
open FluentCassandra.Types
open FluentCassandra.Linq
open Test.Cassandra

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    CreateKeyspace("test1")
    printfn "%s" (ColumnFamilyExists("test1", "table1").ToString())
    printfn "%s" (KeyspaceExists("test1").ToString())
    CreateColumnFamily("test1","table1")
    printfn "%s" (ColumnFamilyExists("test1", "table1").ToString())
    let result = ExecuteNonQuery("test1", "CREATE TABLE table2 (id bigint primary key, name varchar)")
    printfn "%s" (result.ToString())

    let wait = System.Console.ReadLine()
    0
```

Specifically with converting the query string to a UTF8Type, Daniel's approach of utilizing UTF8Type.op_Implicit str worked. You can see how I applied it in the ExecuteNonQuery function above.  Thanks again for your help!